# Почему this не доступен в callback?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Делаю класс для пагинации, использую внутри него обертку для jquery - класс `Request`. Метод `getRecords` - это коллбэк который вешается на `$(window).scroll()`, внутри себя он вызывает класс `Request` чтобы сделать запрос, внутри которого `onRequest` - это коллбек `success` который вызывает `$.ajax()`. Внутри `onRequest` в `this` уже не содержится `Pagination` а содержится объект содержащий данные запроса.

```
export class Pagination{

    constructor (params? :Object){
        //.. more actions
        this.getRecords();
        fn.setOnWindowListener('scroll','pagination',null,(e) => {this.setScrollEvent(e)});
    }

    private setScrollEvent = (e) :void =>{
        let pos = $(e.currentTarget).scrollTop() + this.paginationHeight;
        let height = $(document).height();
        if(pos >= height && !this.doRequest) this.getRecords();
    };

    public getRecords = () :void =>{
        this.doRequest = true;
        //здесь this - ссылка на Pagination
        return new Request({
            url: this.url + this.currentPage,
            type: `GET`,
            dataType: this.requestDataType,
            onRequest: (data) =>{
                //а здесь this превратился в объект $.ajax()
                this.doRequest = false;
                this.currentPage++;
                this.onRecordsLoaded(data);
            }
        }).exec();
    };

}
```

Вопрос в том, как прокинуть `this` из `Pagination` в `onRequest` так чтобы внутри `onRequest` были доступны св-ва `Pagination`?

p.s.

конечно можно перед `new Request()` создать переменную вроде `var _self = this;` и дальше уже в `onRequest` дергать ее, но это уже будет костыль тянущий подход использующийся в es5. Это не вариант, т.к. хочется сделать все красиво.

p.p.s.

Пока сделал таким образом передачу контекста, передавая `this` в `getRecords`,

```
public getRecords = (context: Pagination) :void =>{
        context.doRequest = true;
        return new Request({
            url: context.url + context.currentPage,
            type: `GET`,
            dataType: context.requestDataType,
            onRequest: (data) =>{
                context.doRequest = false;
                context.currentPage++;
                context.onRecordsLoaded(context.context, data);
            }
        }).exec();
    };
```

И в конструкторе таким же способом запоминать контекст класса из которого был создан инстанс `Pagination`:

```
constructor (context :Object, params? :Object){
        this.context = context;
```

Answer (score 1):

callback - это функция. При вызове функции ее контекст устанавливается в зависимости от того как ее вызвали, и в общем случае не совпадает с контекстом внешней функции.

Передать контекст в функцию обратного вызова проще всего через замыкание и локальную переменную:

```
var self = this;
/**/ (data) => {
    // Здесь this изменился - но self осталась прежней!
}
```

Иногда эту переменную еще называют `that` или `_this`. Если вы читали код используемых библиотек - вы должны были обратить внимание на такую конструкцию.

Еще один способ привязать контекст - использование bind:

```
/**/ ((data) => {
    // Здесь this изменился - но self осталась прежней!
}).bind(this);
```

Метод `bind` связывает функцию с контекстом, делая внутренний контекст независимым от способа вызова.

Если бы вы писали на javascript или на свежей версии typescript, вы также могли бы воспользоваться [стрелочными функциями (arrow functions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) из стандарта ECMA 2015, которые специально создавали для решения этой проблемы - но для вашей версии typescript такое решение, видимо, недоступно. Может быть, вам надо просто обновить компилятор typescript...

Comment: `((data) => { }).bind(this);` o_O

Comment: @Qwertiy сам так же на это смотрю. Но если автор вопроса утверждает что у него this теряется - приходится ему верить.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ts версия - 2.x. Я думаю проблема из-за класса Request, в нем так делается запрос `$.ajax(options)
            .done(data => this.onRequest(data))
            .fail(err => this.onError(err))
            .always(data => this.onComplete(data));` вот где-то тут и теряется контекст. Хотя по идее, не должен

Comment: Если контекст сохранен внутри средствами языка - снаружи его не "потерять".